How to animate/increase scale of instances on points one by one, using geo nodes?
I'm trying to create kind of a neural network representation and need to make appear each of the spheres (which are instanced on each of the mesh nodes) one by one, so at frame 0 non on the spheres are visible and then start appearing one by one.
I've tried several ways with geo nodes, I can scale them up but not one at a time. Thanks!


If you are using instances, do you try Scale Instances Node taking advantage of the Selection mask ?

yes, I can choose which instances, but how to do it one by one? like using index so instance 1 scales up, then instance 2, and so on.

There are several ways to do it IMO. You can use the Scene Frame node, plug it into a math node set to divide by say 10 if you want each dot to appear 10 frames after the other, then compare the ouput of the math node to the output of an ID node with a math node set to Less than, and plug the output of the math node into the selection input of the Scale Instances node.

you can use this nodes setup:

to get this:

So by using the instance index and the frame, i fill in the map range node to control the from and to value for the frame, and i scale the instances from 0 to 2.
The "add node" is the animation duration, the "multiply value" is the offset the the animations.
Hope that helps. Happy blending!
